# Paragraph is not responsive when the navigation bar is fixed at the left side

Tags: html, css

I have some problems with my website.

I have set my navigation bar on the left side with a fixed position. My main content is moved to the right using position:absolute, but the problem is, the content is not responsive to the screen. I did not encounter any responsive issue for

when I was working on other projects.

And when the screen is not in full screen, the right content (absolute position) will overlap with the navigation bar (fixed position). [The content is overlapping.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH594.png)
I don't know what is wrong with the code as I have never encounter this kind of problem before.

Please help me with this problem as I have stucked at this problem for a few hours.

You can check my code here:https://codepen.io/legsenfor/pen/rNmbBQo . I won't take too long time as my code is quite short.

this is my HTML code:

```
    <nav id="navbar">
  <header><strong>CSS Documentation</strong></header>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#Introduction" class="nav-link">Introduction</a></li>
  <li><a href="#CSS_Editor" class="nav-link">CSS Editor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#CSS_Selectors" class="nav-link">CSS Selectors</a></li>
  <li><a href="#CSS_Flexbox" class="nav-link">CSS Flexbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#CSS_Grid" class="nav-link" style="border-bottom:solid 1px;">CSS Grid</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main id="main-doc">
  <a id="Introduction"></a>
   <section class="main-section" id="Introduction">
     <header id="Introduction"><strong>Introduction</strong></header>
     <p>
       CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets. It is the language for describing the presentation of Web pages, including colours, layout, and fonts, thus making our web pages presentable to the users.
     </p>
```

this is my CSS code:

```
#navbar{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:300px;
  border: solid 1px;
  position:fixed;
  font-size:30px;  
  background-color:azure;
}

#navbar li{
  list-style:none;
  border-top: solid 1px;
}

#navbar ul{
  padding-left:0;
}

#navbar header{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:10px;
}

.nav-link{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}

#main-doc{
  position:absolute;
  left:350px;
  width:1000px;
  margin:auto;
}

section{
  font-family:Georgia;
  font-size:20px;
}

code{
  display:block;
  width:500px;
  background-color:Azure;
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping out a newbie.

Comment: I stopped reading at ` . My main content is moved to the right using position:absolute, ` . Never use position absolute for that. Position absolute should be used for specific elements. Not the whole content .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I have followed your suggestion and use float properties instead of the position property. and I change the width to 30% and 70% for each section, and it works.